# I can't get the Borderlands 2 profile editor to reduce Badass Rewards?

Tags: borderlands-2

I was playing around with the borderlands 2 profile editor [here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/qbe33lcd38psdgu/Borderlands+2+-+Profile+Editor+v1.0.1.0.zip) to see a few things about damage numbers because I like big numbers in video games, but when I decided that that was boring I tried to revert my changes but found out I can not. I have tried deleting my profile information again to no avail. I'm just trying to find a way to reduce values back to a reasonable level or to reset them to 0.

[image]

Comment: Why not just enter the game as a high-level character and unequip all your weapons?

Comment: Can you post a picture of what the Profile Editor currently shows for you? I've got it and can give you some ideas of what values might make sense.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the values the Profile Editor shows, and a screenshot of what values are shown in-game?

Comment: When you say you can't revert the changes, what happens when you try? Does it show you an error?

Comment: It let's me set the values back to 0 and save the file. But once I load Borderlands 2 back up the values don't actually change. and for reference the values that are only near 100% were before playing with the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so I'm a moron. In the bottom right by default it has Lock All Customizations enabled. Selecting unlock fixes this and lets you reduce the values. Sorry for wasting everyones time.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Wow, those *are* some high numbers.

Here's mine:

[image: Profile]

Every value I have is either 7.6 or 7.2. You can use [the table found on this wiki page](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Badass_Rank) to find valid values to use.

Note also that when you're in-game, you can turn badass rewards off by pressing the Q key (I believe).